# Search date and time format without using like

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in my SQL Server 2008 with format date

```
CHECKTIME
2016-08-10 10:21:03.000
2016-08-10 10:15:42.000
```

Then I search with date today

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHECKINOUT].[USERID],CHECKTIME,[dbo].USERINFO.Name  
FROM [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
 inner join [dbo].[USERINFO] 
on [dbo].USERINFO.USERID = [dbo].CHECKINOUT.USERID  
where CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME like '%2016%'
order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

is working and shows all 2016 dates. But if I change selection with `like '%2016-08-08'` nothing is returned.

I try with condition:

```
where CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME = '2016-0-08'
```

nothing returned...

Any clue for my problem? Basically I just show data today.

Thanks

Comment: Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: If your data is a datetime, you can use datepart function to extract your part and then you can apply a logic with between to take a period

Comment: Checktime(datetime, not null)

Answer (score 1):

Yes your first clue is `2016-0-08` this is wrong. There is no such thing as Month = 0.

Second, `[CHECKINOUT].CHECKTIME` is in format `2016-08-08 10:21:03.000` and you are comparing this with `'2016-08-08'`. So the result is false.

Try converting the `[CHECKINOUT].CHECKTIME` to `varchar` using appropriate format to match with `'2016-08-10'`

I used dateformat `120` which is like `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` and takes only first 10 letters from it using `Varchar(10)`. Thus I get only `yyyy-mm-dd`. More [Date Formats](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[CHECKINOUT].[USERID],CHECKTIME,[dbo].USERINFO.Name  
FROM 
    dbo.[CHECKINOUT]
Inner Join 
   [dbo].[USERINFO] 
On 
   [dbo].USERINFO.USERID = [dbo].CHECKINOUT.USERID  
Where 
    Convert(Varchar(10),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,120) =  '2016-08-08'
Order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be

`'2016-08-08%'` not `'%2016-08-08'`
because in Your version You are looking for text before 2016 not after whole date.

Comment: i have try   where CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME like '2016-08-08%' no result , i do it in sql management Studio

Comment: This is `'%2016-08-08'` totally fine.

Answer (score 0):

For the above query you should use convert instead of like and you can check.

where CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME = SELECT CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)

you can check the below link.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHECKINOUT].[USERID],CHECKTIME,[dbo].USERINFO.Name  
FROM [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
 inner join [dbo].[USERINFO] 
on [dbo].USERINFO.USERID = [dbo].CHECKINOUT.USERID  
where Convert(Date,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) in ('2016/08/08')
order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

Will return all the records for a specific date

If you need more fuzzy searching tryin

```
where Convert(Date,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) like '%2016/08%')
order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

Which should return everything for August

-------- Additional Thoughts -----

If you wanted to make things a little more dynamic and meaning you never had modify the report if you are always running i would do something like the two following options

If i wanted to only ever show what i was raised Today I would use the following

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHECKINOUT].[USERID],CHECKTIME,[dbo].USERINFO.Name  
FROM [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
 inner join [dbo].[USERINFO] 
on [dbo].USERINFO.USERID = [dbo].CHECKINOUT.USERID  
where Convert(Date,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) in (Convert(date(GetDate())))
order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

and if i wanted to look at records from only yesterday i would use the following

```
SELECT [dbo].[CHECKINOUT].[USERID],CHECKTIME,[dbo].USERINFO.Name  
FROM [dbo].[CHECKINOUT]
 inner join [dbo].[USERINFO] 
on [dbo].USERINFO.USERID = [dbo].CHECKINOUT.USERID  
where Convert(Date,CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) in (Convert(date(GetDate()-1)))
order by CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME desc
```

Answer (score -2):

try this DATEPART() function. I hope this works